# Converting SQL query with joins to JPA

Tags: java, sql, jpa

I have this SQL query:

```
select ts.scorename from content_package cp 
join content_package_content_package_components cpcps on cpcps.content_package = cp.id
join content_package_component cpc on cpc.id = cpcps.content_package_components
join tests t on t.id = cpc.assessment
join test_scores ts on ts.tests_id = t.id
where cp.tag = 'C_TS_EN_ABSA_G_'
```

And want to convert it to JPA, ideally Specifications - is this possible?

Comment: What about this query would make you think that it can't be written in JPA?

Comment: Any JPQL query uses entities. You don't provide the entities. You also don't provide what you have tried. And the JPA API has no such thing called "Specifications"; that is Spring

Answer (score 0):

you can write this query in JPQL but firs you need to create POJO class of your models. if you are using Intelij idea you can create your models in it by going to persistence section ,right click on your data source and select generate persistence mapping by (hibernate or database schema). after creating models you should change your table names to pojo classes in query and so on ....